# How to perform time series analysis on a categorical dataset using neural networks

Tags: keras, neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network, forecasting

I have a dataset with 2 columns date & state(36 unique values). I want to do time series analysis using nueral networks on this dataset (keras is recommended). I searched a lot in internet, but I'm getting answers for numerical data. Please someone help me how to move forward with this dataset.

Comment: Do you try to find out how to encode your categorical input data?

Comment: I encoded the data into One hot encoding form...
But then not getting how to move forward

Comment: Okay, so you have dataset with one numeric feature one hot encoded categorical feature and you want help with setup model for such data?

Comment: yeah... Need help in model... This is my model I'm going to built. Basically I have no idea how to do it...

When I give a range of dates, it should predict the state..

Comment: I mean this is my first model*
typo error

Answer (score 3):

Ok I try to answer. I assume that you have tensorflow installed. You mnetion  that you have data at such form

```
date          state
01.01.2018    state1
02.01.2018    state2
....
```

You want to perform time series prediction. I guess that you no need date column feeded to the network. So your basic setup is, you give n states as input and expect model to predict. You write right that you need somehow encode the categorical variable. You choose one-hot encoding. I advice you to look at [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/) and [this](https://skymind.ai/wiki/word2vec). But for now we assume that you use one-hot encoding.

Assume that your dataset looks like:

```
state1
state2
state1
state3
state2
state1
state1
state2
```

Your first choice is define the n(numer of samples which you use for predicition n+1 sample). For now consider n 3. Which mens that your input data should looks like:

```
[[state1, state2, state1],
 [state2, state1, state3],
 [state1, state3, state2],
 [state3, state2, state1],
 [state2, state1, state1]]
```

And outputs will be:

```
[[state3],
 [state2],
 [state1],
 [state1],
 [state2]]
```

You use one hot(please look at embeding layers and word2vec) and with this example it means that

```
state1 = [1, 0, 0]
state2 = [0, 1, 0]
state3 = [0, 0, 1]
```

About model, I assume that you plan to use LSTM which at Keras requires input to be shaped as **samples x timesteps x features**. So for this example it means that your input data should looks like

```
[[[[1], [0], [0]],  [[0], [1], [0]], [[1], [0], [0]]],
 [[[0], [1], [0]],  [[1], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [1]]],
 ...
```

When you have data at this form, model will looks like

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
#create input output pairs in sense of example
x, y = createDataset()
#define model topology
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(nb_of_units, input_shape(time_steps, features)))
model.add(Dense(size_of_one_hot_vector, activation="softmax"))
#select optimizer, loss and metric
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['acc'])
#fit model to data
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=nb_of_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Sir, I have some doubts here.
Why are we defining samples here. 
Sir, you said input data should be shaped as
samples x timestamps x features.

What should I do shape data in this form

What is this variable timesteps and features...
Can you please enlight me on this variables

Comment: Samples are number of data points. You use now one-hot encoding and you say your categorical variable have 36 unique values, which means you one-hot vector will have length 36. Every element of this one-hot vector is considered as feature, time steps tells how many past values will be used for predicition next value and select this number is completely your choice. So elements of one hot vector are features and one hot vectors are timesteps.

Comment: Sir, I have lot of doubts. Can I have any social media link... Like email or linked in. So that i can clear my doubts more freely

Comment: This post is very helpful for my problem. Here is the question I had but it seems no one so far has an answer for me. I would appreciate if you can give me a clue as to how apply it to my specific problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347344/how-to-make-a-predictive-model-using-a-timeseries-data-consisted-of-binary-infor

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a convolutional neural network for your solution? Otherwise you can use an [LSTM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), which are pretty common for time series analytics. You can find some examples for LSTM networks in keras here:

1. [First](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)
2. [Second](https://www.kaggle.com/ternaryrealm/lstm-time-series-explorations-with-keras)
3. [Third](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/)

Comment: Sir, these links have numerical data. But mine is categorical one. I have already checked these. I want LSTM sir